# How to do an update + join in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Basically, I want to do this:

```
update vehicles_vehicle v 
    join shipments_shipment s on v.shipment_id=s.id 
set v.price=s.price_per_vehicle;
```

I'm pretty sure that would work in MySQL (my background), but it doesn't seem to work in postgres. The error I get is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "join"
LINE 1: update vehicles_vehicle v join shipments_shipment s on v.shi...
                                  ^
```

Surely there's an easy way to do this, but I can't find the proper syntax. So, how would I write this In PostgreSQL?

Comment: Postgres syntax is different: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-update.html

Comment: vehicles_vehicle, shipments_shipment? That's an interesting table naming convention

Comment: @CodeAndCats Haha...it does look funny doesn't it? I think I was using Django at the time, and the tables are grouped by feature. So there would have been a view `vehicles_*` tables, and a few `shipments_*` tables.

Comment: Some care should be taken if the join is performed on a *non-unique column*. This may lead to a [non deterministic outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75592208/4808122).

Answer (score 1163, accepted):

The [UPDATE syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) is:

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_list ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

In your case I think you want this:

```
UPDATE vehicles_vehicle AS v 
SET price = s.price_per_vehicle
FROM shipments_shipment AS s
WHERE v.shipment_id = s.id
```

Or if you need to join on two or more tables:

```
UPDATE table_1 t1
SET foo = 'new_value'
FROM table_2 t2
    JOIN table_3 t3 ON t3.id = t2.t3_id
WHERE
    t2.id = t1.t2_id
    AND t3.bar = True;
```

Comment: If the update relies on a whole list of table joins, should those be in the UPDATE section or the FROM section?

Comment: @ted.strauss: The FROM can contain a list of tables.

Comment: coming from mysql it's unintuitive that the same join used for `select` won't also `update` just by adding a `set` phrase  :(   still - the syntax for this is probably easier for a newcomer to sql to master.

Comment: @WEBjuju my thoughts exactly, converting a select statement into an update requires an additional step with this method which is inconvenient. The syntax is also not quite as intuitive this way (in my opinion).

Comment: I got an error with the alias in the update line; I removed it and there was NOT an error.

Comment: I have no idea how many times I have visited this answer. Wish I could update it more than once.

Answer (score 283):

The answer of Mark Byers is the optimal in this situation. 
Though in more complex situations you can take the select query that returns rowids and calculated values and attach it to the update query like this:

```
with t as (
  -- Any generic query which returns rowid and corresponding calculated values
  select t1.id as rowid, f(t2, t2) as calculatedvalue
  from table1 as t1
  join table2 as t2 on t2.referenceid = t1.id
)
update table1
set value = t.calculatedvalue
from t
where id = t.rowid
```

This approach lets you develop and test your select query and in two steps convert it to the update query.

So in your case the result query will be:

```
with t as (
    select v.id as rowid, s.price_per_vehicle as calculatedvalue
    from vehicles_vehicle v 
    join shipments_shipment s on v.shipment_id = s.id 
)
update vehicles_vehicle
set price = t.calculatedvalue
from t
where id = t.rowid
```

Note that column aliases are mandatory otherwise PostgreSQL will complain about the ambiguity of the column names.

Comment: I really like this one because I'm always a tad nervous with taking my "select" off the top and replacing it with an "update," especially with multiple joins.  This reduces the number of SQL dumps I should have to do before mass updates. :)

Comment: Not sure why, but the CTE version of this query is way way faster than the "plain join" solutions above

Comment: The other advantage of this solution is the ability join from more than two tables to get to your final calculated value by using multiple joins in the with / select statement.

Comment: This is awesome. I had my select crafted and like @dannysauer, I was scared of the conversion. This simply does it for me. Perfect!

Comment: regardless of method (join or cte) i have:
SQL state: 55000
Detail: Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
seems like it should be simple/common operation

Comment: Your first SQL example has a syntax error. "update t1" cannot use the alias from  the t subquery, it needs to use the table name: "update table1". You do this correctly in your second example.

Comment: Just to emphasise: the column aliases must be present on the columns within the CTE, not the outer query. I had forgotten those alliances and it wasn't working, once I added them I went to the moon

Comment: This was a lifesaver, regular UPDATE/FROM with a join was running indefinitely on my table and this ran in no time!

Comment: It's also possible to JOIN any number of tables without a subquery (see accepted answer).  If you have a SELECT, you just replace FROM with UPDATE, take the first JOIN and make it a FROM clause (moving the ON condition into the WHERE clause), and then the rest of the JOINs can stay as is.

Answer (score 192):

Let me explain a little more by my example.

Task: correct info, where abiturients (students about to leave secondary school) have submitted applications to university earlier, than they got school certificates (yes, they got certificates earlier, than they were issued (by certificate date specified). So, we will increase application submit date to fit certificate issue date.

Thus. next MySQL-like statement:

```sql
UPDATE applications a
JOIN (
    SELECT ap.id, ab.certificate_issued_at
    FROM abiturients ab
    JOIN applications ap 
    ON ab.id = ap.abiturient_id 
    WHERE ap.documents_taken_at::date < ab.certificate_issued_at
) b
ON a.id = b.id
SET a.documents_taken_at = b.certificate_issued_at;
```

Becomes PostgreSQL-like in such a way

```sql
UPDATE applications a
SET documents_taken_at = b.certificate_issued_at         -- we can reference joined table here
FROM abiturients b                                       -- joined table
WHERE 
    a.abiturient_id = b.id AND                           -- JOIN ON clause
    a.documents_taken_at::date < b.certificate_issued_at -- Subquery WHERE
```

As you can see, original subquery `JOIN`'s `ON` clause have become one of `WHERE` conditions, which is conjucted by `AND` with others, which have been moved from subquery with no changes. And there is no more need to `JOIN` table with itself (as it was in subquery).

Comment: How would you join a third table?

Comment: You just `JOIN` it as usual in the `FROM` list:
```FROM abiturients b JOIN addresses c ON c.abiturient_id = b.id```

Comment: @Envek - You can't use JOIN there alas, I just checked. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-update.html

Comment: @AdrianSmith, you can't use JOIN in UPDATE itself, but can use it in UPDATE's `from_list` clause (which is PostgreSQL's extension of SQL). Also, see notes about joining tables caveats on the link you provided.

Comment: @Envek can you give a from_list example with multiple joins as well ? a to b might not be direct link, sometimes c is there too and then we have to do a.c_id = c.id and c.b_id = b.id , to connect a and b.

Answer (score 153):

For those actually wanting to do a `JOIN` you can also use:

```
UPDATE a
SET price = b_alias.unit_price
FROM      a AS a_alias
LEFT JOIN b AS b_alias ON a_alias.b_fk = b_alias.id
WHERE a_alias.unit_name LIKE 'some_value' 
AND a.id = a_alias.id;
```

You can use the a_alias in the `SET` section on the right of the equals sign if needed.
The fields on the left of the equals sign don't require a table reference as they are deemed to be from the original "a" table.

Comment: Considering this is the first answer with an actual join in (and not inside a with subquery), this should be the real accepted answer. Either that or this question should be renamed to avoid confusion whether postgresql supports joins in update or not.

Comment: It should be noted that according to the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-update.html), listing the target table in the from clause will cause the target table to be self-joined.  Less confidently, it also appears to me that this is a cross-self-join, which may have unintended results and/or performance implications.

Comment: Just FYI, I tried this and the number of rows updated was different than the number of rows returned from the select query with same join and where clauses.

Comment: I tried this with CockroachDB on a test env and it updated every record in the table regardless of `JOIN` and `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 40):

For those wanting to do a JOIN that updates ONLY the rows your join returns use:

```
UPDATE a
SET price = b_alias.unit_price
FROM      a AS a_alias
LEFT JOIN b AS b_alias ON a_alias.b_fk = b_alias.id
WHERE a_alias.unit_name LIKE 'some_value' 
AND a.id = a_alias.id
--the below line is critical for updating ONLY joined rows
AND a.pk_id = a_alias.pk_id;
```

This was mentioned above but only through a comment..Since it's critical to getting the correct result posting NEW answer that Works

Comment: @FlipVernooij When posting a comment referring to a link, please be specific about the part of the link being reference and/or quote the part, unless the entire link applies or the applicable portion of the link is *very* obvious. In this case there is nothing whatsoever obvious about what you are referring to at the link referenced, This leaves all of us bewildered, after wasting time searching the documentation linked and returning with the question, "*What side-effects??*"

Comment: @FlipVernooij With the addition of the last line in the answer, `AND a.pk_id = a_alias.pk_id`, *there is no cross-join here* and the answer *is* valid. The link and reference to Ben's comment can only lead readers to a wild goose chase and a complete waste of their time, trying to understand what you are referring to.

Comment: I tried this one, and it seemed to be working https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-update-join/

Answer (score 11):

Here we go:

```
UPDATE vehicles_vehicle v
SET price = s.price_per_vehicle
FROM shipments_shipment s
WHERE v.shipment_id = s.id;
```

Simple as I could make it.

Comment: @littlegreen You sure about that? Doesn't the `join` constrain it?

Comment: @mpen I can confirm that it updates all records to one value.  it does not do what you would expect.

Comment: Why is some of this answer's text cross-out?

Comment: From an earlier revision. Apparently it didn't work so I crossed it out. I'll delete it now.

Comment: I found the similar one in a blog https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-update-join/ and it seems like working as expected. @AdamGordonBell

Answer (score 4):

To add something quite important to all the great answers above, when you want to update a `join-table`, you may have 2 problems:

- you **cannot** use the table you want to update to `JOIN` another one
- Postgres wants a `ON` clause after the `JOIN` so you **cannot** only use `where` clauses.

This means that basically, the following queries are not valid:

```sql
UPDATE join_a_b
SET count = 10
FROM a
JOIN b on b.id = join_a_b.b_id -- Not valid since join_a_b is used here
WHERE a.id = join_a_b.a_id
AND a.name = 'A'
AND b.name = 'B'
```

```sql
UPDATE join_a_b
SET count = 10
FROM a
JOIN b -- Not valid since there is no ON clause
WHERE a.id = join_a_b.a_id 
AND b.id = join_a_b.b_id
a.name = 'A'
AND b.name = 'B'
```

Instead, you must use all the tables in the `FROM` clause like this:

```sql
UPDATE join_a_b
SET count = 10
FROM a, b
WHERE a.id = join_a_b.a_id 
AND b.id = join_a_b.b_id 
AND a.name = 'A'
AND b.name = 'B'
```

It might be straightforward for some but I got stuck on this problem wondering what's going on so hopefully, it will help others.

Answer (score 3):

WORKS PERFECT!!!

POSTGRE SQL - UPDATE With a JOIN

BELOW CODE - Check the positioning of columns and IDs as below:

If you place it exactly as below, then only it will work!

```
---IF you want to update This table1 using table2

UPDATE table1
SET attribute1 = table2.attribute2
FROM table2
WHERE table2.product_ID = table1.product_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple SQL that updates Mid_Name on the Name3 table using the Middle_Name field from Name:

```
update name3
set mid_name = name.middle_name
from name
where name3.person_id = name.person_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

The link below has a example that resolve and helps understant better how use `update` and `join` with postgres.

```
UPDATE product
SET net_price = price - price * discount
FROM
product_segment
WHERE
product.segment_id = product_segment.id;
```

See: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/

Answer (score 2):

First Table Name: tbl_table1 (tab1).
Second Table Name: tbl_table2 (tab2).

Set the tbl_table1's ac_status column to "INACTIVE"

```
update common.tbl_table1 as tab1
set ac_status= 'INACTIVE' --tbl_table1's "ac_status"
from common.tbl_table2 as tab2
where tab1.ref_id= '1111111' 
and tab2.rel_type= 'CUSTOMER';
```

Answer (score 1):

To UPDATE one Table using another, in PostGRE SQL / AWS (SQL workbench).

In PostGRE SQL, this is how you need to use joins in UPDATE Query:

```
UPDATE TABLEA set COLUMN_FROM_TABLEA = COLUMN_FROM_TABLEB FROM TABLEA,TABLEB WHERE FILTER_FROM_TABLEA = FILTER_FROM_TABLEB;

Example:
```

```
Update Employees Set Date_Of_Exit = Exit_Date_Recorded , Exit_Flg = 1 From Employees, Employee_Exit_Clearance Where Emp_ID = Exit_Emp_ID
```

Table A - Employees Columns in Table A - Date_Of_Exit,Emp_ID,Exit_Flg Table B is - Employee_Exit_Clearance Columns in Table B - Exit_Date_Recorded,Exit_Emp_ID

1760 rows affected

Execution time: 29.18s

Answer (score 1):

Some care should be taken if the join is performed on a *non-unique column*. I.e. the result of the join produces  more values that can be used in the update.

Some RDMS raise an exception is this case, but PostgreSQL apparently performs the update with a *non deterministic* outcome.

**Example**

Tested on 14.1

```
create table tab as
select * from  (values
(1,'a'),
(2,'b') 
) t(id, att);
```

We use a CTE where the `id = 1` id giving two possible values for the update. Using the `order by` in the CTE we get a different results.

```
with t as ( 
select * from  (values
(1,'c'),
(1,'d') 
) t(id, att)
order by 2   /* Based on this order different update is performed */
)
update tab 
set att = t.att
from t
where tab.id = t.id
```

With the *ascendig* order the column is updated to the value of `d` (highest value)

```
id|att|
--+---+
 1|d  |
 2|b  |
```

while using a *descending* order in the CTE the column is updated to the value of `c` (lowest value)

```
id|att|
--+---+
 1|c  |
 2|b  |
```

The **moral of the story** always check if the join produce a *unique result*.

The [relevant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) part of the documentation

> When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

Answer (score 0):

--goal: update selected columns with join (postgres)--

```
UPDATE table1 t1      
SET    column1 = 'data' 
FROM   table1    
       RIGHT JOIN table2   
               ON table2.id = table1.id   
WHERE  t1.id IN     
(SELECT table2.id   FROM   table2   WHERE  table2.column2 = 12345)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first way is slower than the second way.

First:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
  page int := 10000;
  min_id bigint; max_id bigint;
BEGIN
  SELECT max(id),min(id) INTO max_id,min_id FROM opportunities;
  FOR j IN min_id..max_id BY page LOOP 
    UPDATE opportunities SET sec_type = 'Unsec'
    FROM opportunities AS opp
    INNER JOIN accounts AS acc
    ON opp.account_id = acc.id
    WHERE acc.borrower = true
    AND opp.sec_type IS NULL
    AND opp.id >= j AND opp.id < j+page;
    COMMIT;            
  END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

Second:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
  page int := 10000;
  min_id bigint; max_id bigint;
BEGIN
  SELECT max(id),min(id) INTO max_id,min_id FROM opportunities;
  FOR j IN min_id..max_id BY page LOOP
    UPDATE opportunities AS opp 
    SET sec_type = 'Unsec'
    FROM accounts AS acc
    WHERE opp.account_id = acc.id
    AND opp.sec_type IS NULL
    AND acc.borrower = true 
    AND opp.id >= j AND opp.id < j+page;
    COMMIT;            
  END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have the value in one column but instead had to calculate it from the other table (in this example `price_per_vehicle` from `shipments_shipment`).
Then assuming that `shipments_shipment` has `price` and `vehicle_id` columns the update for a specific vehicle could look like this:

```sql
-- Specific vehicle in this example is with id = 5
WITH prices AS (
    SELECT SUM(COALESCE(s.price, 0)) AS price_per_vehicle
    FROM shipments_shipment AS s
    WHERE s.vehicle_id = 5
)
UPDATE vehicles_vehicle AS v
SET v.price = prices.price_per_vehicle
FROM prices
WHERE v.id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: do not use, execution time increases quadratically

It's a pity that the runtime is so bad, because the syntax was very elegant.
I'm leaving this answer up to save others from going down this path.

---

This answer is different from the rest because
**you don't have to repeat the join condition.**

- You join once in the FROM clause
- and the WHERE clause checks that rows from X are present in (X as X_joined join Y).

As a result this works with natural joins, which is very nice.

#### Example query

Say that you have a table `shipment` that you want to augment with information from table `vehicle`, and both tables have a column `vehicle_id` so you can use `NATURAL JOIN`.

```
---- DO NOT USE, quadratic runtime ----

EXPLAIN UPDATE shipment
SET shipment.speed = vehicle.average_speed
FROM
    shipment s_joined NATURAL JOIN vehicle
WHERE
    -- This is the magic condition
    -- (EDIT: ... it probably causes the quadratic runtime, too)
    shipment = s_joined
    -- any further limitations go here:
    AND shipment.destination = 'Perth'
```

#### Minimal working example

```
-- A table with shipments, some with missing speeds
create temporary table shipment (
    vehicle_id varchar(20),
    cargo varchar(20),
    speed integer
);
insert into shipment values
    ('cart', 'flowers', 60),
    ('boat', 'cabbage', null),
    ('cart', 'potatos', null),
    ('foot', 'carrots', null);

-- A table with vehicles whose average speed we know about
create temporary table vehicle (
    vehicle_id varchar(20),
    average_speed integer
);
insert into vehicle values
    ('cart', 6),
    ('foot', 5);

-- If the shipment has vehicle info, update its speed
---- DO NOT USE, quadratic runtime ----
UPDATE shipment
SET   speed = vehicle.average_speed
FROM  shipment as s_joined natural join vehicle
WHERE shipment = s_joined
      AND shipment.speed is null;

-- After:
TABLE shipment;
┌────────────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ vehicle_id │  cargo  │ speed │
├────────────┼─────────┼───────┤
│ cart       │ flowers │    60 │ <- not updated: speed was not null
│ boat       │ cabbage │       │ <- not updated: no boat in join
│ cart       │ potatos │     6 │ <- updated 
│ foot       │ carrots │     5 │ <- updated
└────────────┴─────────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether your joins are proper or not you can run your update query in transaction, using this you can run select query on original table which gives you exactly those results which you are looking for, and after confirmation you can finalize the query.

```
BEGIN;
-- Begin the transaction

UPDATE schema.village vill
SET wst_id = vill_view.wst_id_023::INT, --if you want to cast the column type
    wst_dist = vill_view.wst_dist_023::numeric --if you want to cast the column type
FROM schema.village_view vill_view 
WHERE vill.id = vill_view.id::double precision; --if you want to cast the column type

-- Verify the result
SELECT * FROM schema.village

-- ROLLBACK; -- if your query fails or fills that something is wrong you can reverse the all updates and table will remain as original
-- COMMIT -- if you fills all are good (no return to original table once commited)
```