# Update the same data on many specific rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to update multiple rows. I have a lot of ids that specify which row to update (around 12k ids).

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I know I could do

```
UPDATE table SET col="value" WHERE id = 1 OR id = 24 OR id = 27 OR id = ....repeatx10000
```

But I figure that would give bad performance, right? So is there a better way to specify which ids to update?

Postgresql version is 9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of strict update performance not much will change. All rows with given IDs must be found and updated.

One thing that may simplify your call is to use the `in` keyword. It goes like this:

`UPDATE table SET col="value" WHERE id in ( 1,24,27, ... );`

I would also suggest making sure that the ID's are in the same order like the index on the id suggests, probably ascending.

Answer (score 2):

Put your IDs in a table.  Then do something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET col="value" WHERE id in (select id from table_of_ids_to_update)
```

Or if the source of your ids is some other query, use that query to get the ids you want to update.

```
UPDATE table SET col="value" WHERE id in (
       select distinct id from some_other_table
           where some_condition_for_updating is true
           ... etc. ...
    )
```

For more complex cases of updating based on another table, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7869611/1919238) gives a good example.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table SET col="value" WHERE id in ( select id from table);

Also make indexing on your id field so, you will get better performance.

Comment: Primary keys are indexed by default.

Comment: if it's primary key then it's ok

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that if you *do* reference a table as @dan1111 suggests, don't use `in (select ..)`, and certainly avoid `distinct`!  Instead, use `exists` -

```
update table
set col = value
where exists (
        select from other_table
        where other_table.id = table.id
      )
```

This ensures that the reference table is only scanned as much as it is needed.