# update query from select statement only update if the field is empty

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to write a sql statement to update a column of a table from another tables column. But I only want to update the column if its empty.

For example:

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    Table.col1 = other_table.col1,
FROM
    Table
INNER JOIN
    other_table
ON
    Table.id = other_table.id
```

but I want to set the Table.col1 value only if that value is empty. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: `where Table.col1 is null` ? Depending on what you mean by empty...

Answer (score 11):

Define empty?

But really all you need is a WHERE clause like

```
UPDATE Table
   SET Table.col1 = other_table.col1,
  FROM Table
       INNER JOIN
       other_table ON Table.id = other_table.id
 WHERE Table.col IS NULL  --or whatever your empty condition is
```

In Postgre you may need a different syntax ([How to do an update + join in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql)):

```
UPDATE Table
   SET Table.col1 = other_table.col1,
  FROM Table
      ,other_table 
 WHERE Table.id = other_table.id
   AND Table.col IS NULL  --or whatever your empty condition is
```

Comment: To capitalize on @KarlKieninger's statement, there's a major difference between a nulled entry and an empty entry (i.e., '').

Comment: why would it throws the error of "table name Table spcecified more than once -> here Table is my table name.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis because you make a join in an update statement. This can be solved (but usually different between dbms). So what's your dbms ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus i am using postgres

Comment: Oh, in postgre it's different. you need to change the join syntax a bit, but your aander is still to tack on the appropriate where empty condition. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql