# PostgreSQL Update Where And

Tags: postgresql

My problem is I got 2 table 1 is coach and 1 is tool

- coach (*cid*, forename, surname, toolNo )
- tool (toolNo , registNo )

I want to change the coach "Will Smith" 's toolNo to 10 by using the registNo.
However my code change everyone's toolNo but not only will smith's one.

```
insert into coach values ('c2','will','smith',5)
insert into tool values ('10', 'R123')

    UPDATE coach
SET toolNo = t.toolNo 
From coach c,  tool t
WHERE t.registNo = 'R123'  
AND c.forename ='Will'
AND c.surname = 'smith';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When joining in an UPDATE statement you only need list the tables to which you are joining in the FROM statement, but the table you are updating since that is already stated at the top of the query before `SET`.

Furthermore, according to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql) you have to use the old-school method of joining without the `ON` clause.

```
UPDATE coach
   SET coachtoolNo = t.toolNo 
  FROM tool t 
 WHERE t.registNo = 'R123'  
   AND coach.forename ='Will'
   AND coach.hsurname = 'smith';
```

What you have above in the question is a cross join between Coach and Tool, which is then cross joined again with Coach causing every record to update.

Comment: i have put a inner join and ON but it still change all of the coach's toolNo

Comment: That's curious. I wish sqlfiddle.com would wake up so I could play a bit. The coffee hasn't kicked in yet, so just staring at the SQL isn't helping much.

Comment: OK coffee is kicking in... Updating the answer now.

Comment: That still might need to be tweaked a bit... but overall the idea is right. Read more on UPDATEs in Postgres at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html

Comment: Yes and No... Looks like you cannot use an ON clause in a Postgres UPDATE stataement, but have to join the old school way. Some expert I turned out to be. I think I'll retire from SO for the day o_0

Comment: using the old school way doesnt have any affect

Comment: i have solve it out when remove the coach.toolno = t.toolno in WHERE

Comment: Oh thank goodness. I thought perhaps I'm losing my mind. I still think I'm losing it, but at least it's not negatively impacting your query any longer.