# How to do *this particular* update + join in PostgreSQL 9.2.13?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Alright. I know that this use case [already has a question devoted to it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql/24412833#24412833) but I have tried just about any syntax there and I am getting desperate.

This is my query:

```
with ids as (
  select t.id ntid, ot.id otid, p.id npid, op.id opid, ot.company_id ocid, t.company_id ncid
  from product_template t
  inner join product_template ot on t.multicompany_old_id = ot.id
  inner join product_product p on p.product_tmpl_id = t.id
  inner join product_product op on op.product_tmpl_id = ot.id
)
update ol
set product_id = i.npid
from sale_order_line ol
inner join sale_order o on ol.order_id = o.id
inner join product_product p on ol.product_id = p.id
inner join ids i on p.id = i.opid and o.company_id = i.ncid;
```

Variations I have tried:

```
update [sale_order_line] ol
set [ol.]product_id = i.npid
from...

update sale_order_line ol
set ol.product_id = i.npid
inner join ....

update sale_order_line ol
set product_id = i.npid
from sale_order o on ol.order_id = o.id
inner join product_product p on ol.product_id = p.id
inner join ids i on p.id = i.opid and o.company_id = i.ncid
where ol.order_id = o.id;
```

Nothing works. Could someone help me?
I guess a solution for the following simplified case also suffices:

```
update T
set T.value = J.value
from some_table T
inner join joined_table J on J.some_table_id = T.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
WITH ids AS (
    SELECT
        t.id ntid,
        ot.id otid,
        p.id npid,
        op.id opid,
        ot.company_id ocid,
        t.company_id ncid
    FROM product_template t
        INNER JOIN product_template ot ON t.multicompany_old_id = ot.id
        INNER JOIN product_product p ON p.product_tmpl_id = t.id
        INNER JOIN product_product op ON op.product_tmpl_id = ot.id
)
UPDATE sale_order_line
SET product_id = i.npid
FROM sale_order_line ol
    INNER JOIN sale_order o ON ol.order_id = o.id
    INNER JOIN product_product p ON ol.product_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN ids i ON p.id = i.opid AND o.company_id = i.ncid
WHERE sale_order_line.id = ol.id;
```

The idea is that table that you want to update is kind of outside of the `FROM` part, and to make an update right you need to mark in which cases you need to update data with `WHERE` part.

Comment: This is mysql-syntax. In postgres you dont have to add the target for the update to the from list.

Comment: @wildplasser so you say `where` can be omitted?

Comment: No, `from sale_order_line ol` can be omitted, but that will cause some reshuffling of terms to be needed.

Comment: @wildplasser cool, I'll try tomorrow and tune my answer, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can leave this answer as it is, and do the tuning in wildplasser's answer, and then (since i have the tables here) I'll test it until the errors disappear

Comment: Putting the target table into the `FROM` clause of an UPDATE statement is almost always an error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add/join the *target* table in the update to the `FROM` // 'JOIN' list; it is already in the range table.

```
WITH ids AS (
  SELECT t.id ntid, ot.id otid, p.id npid
        , op.id opid, ot.company_id ocid, t.company_id ncid
  FROM product_template t
  JOIN product_template ot ON t.multicompany_old_id = ot.id 
  JOIN product_product p ON p.product_tmpl_id = t.id
  JOIN product_product op ON op.product_tmpl_id = ot.id 
)
UPDATE sale_order_line ol -- <<-- target table has an alias
SET product_id = i.npid   -- <<-- product_id SHOULD NOT use this alias
FROM ids i 
JOIN sale_order o ON o.company_id = i.ncid;
JOIN product_product p ON p.id = i.opid
WHERE ol.product_id = p.id   -- <<-- target table is linked    
AND ol.order_id = o.id       -- <<-- to the source(s) here
        ;
```

Comment: Error in query: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "ol"
LINE 11: join product_product p on ol.product_id = p.id
HINT: There is an entry for table "ol", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to reshuffle the joined tables a bit. BRB.

Comment: Still gives the same error. And the semicolons are in the wrong place too. Plus, Yuri beat you to it :-) His query works. But thanks a lot