# Update a table when join with other table using Case in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update, case

[image]

I have 2 tables wherein I need the result as follows :
 If the country name is 'United States' then the region should be hardcoded as 'Mexico' & if the country name is 'Taiwan' then the region should be hardcoded as 'China' and for the rest it should be joined with the other table.

I have tried this query in Postgresql:

```
CASE 
    WHEN test.hypno.country_name hp RETURN 'United States'
        THEN UPDATE test.expected_details ed SET ed.place = 'Mexico'
    ELSE UPDATE test.expected_details ed 
         SET ed.place = hp.area_region 
         WHERE ed.WORK = hp.country_name
END
```

How do I include another hardcode case for country 'Taiwan'? 
Also, my query doesn't seem to be working in Postgresql.

Comment: You should include names and schema for all the table required for the query. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
 
 Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: test is the schema name, hypno and expected_details are table names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cant do the full query because you miss the schema, not sure if you alias `hp = hypno` or what field join both tables. But you want something like this

[How to do an update + join in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql)

```
UPDATE test.expected_details ed 
SET ed.place = CASE WHEN hp.country_name = 'United States' THEN 'Mexico'
                    WHEN hp.country_name = 'Taiwan' THEN 'China'
                    ELSE hp.area_region 
               END
FROM test.hypno hp
WHERE ed.work = hp.country_name
```

Comment: test is the schema name, hypno and expected_details are table names.. hp is the hypno table. I am joining using countries i.e.  ed.work = hp.country_name.  
I tried with the above code but I am getting an error : Syntax error at or near FROM.

Comment: the "end" was missing from the case statement. But now I am getting an error of "ed" of relation expected_details does not exist

Comment: Worked fine now... I removed table alias ed from SET operation and made it to SET place = ...            Thanks !

Comment: I make all your correction, except remove `ed` alias, not sure why give you error let me know how looks now. remember the upvote