# Liquibase: postgres fails, mysql - ok

Tags: mysql, postgresql, liquibase-hibernate

A pretty simple Spring application made to run using different DataSources. 
In it I have a liquibase change-set which involves this sql:

```
<sql>
  UPDATE home_description hd
  INNER JOIN home h ON
  hd.id = h.description_id
  SET hd.home_id = h.id
</sql>
```

While this statement runs perfectly fine on a MySQL database, it doesn't work on PostgreSQL.

This is the exception:

```
Error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INNER"
  Position: 46
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INNER"
```

Is there a way to rewrite this statement that both MySQL and PostgreSQL accept this? Thanks!

Comment: [This answer on use of `UPDATE` with join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql) might help.

Comment: @tadman I'm not very strong with sql. Will the solution outlined there work with both mysql and postgresql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<sql>
UPDATE home_description AS hd
SET home_id = h.id
FROM home AS h
WHERE hd.id = h.description_id
</sql>
```

This works in PostgreSql, but not in MySql. Although it fixed my problem.