# Update statement with joins

Tags: postgresql

I must create migration to update question image attribute but i need to check some attributes from other tables, my schema looks like this:

```
question {
id,
name,
groupId,
imageUrl -> i need to update this
}

group {
id, 
name, 
quizId
}

quiz {
id,
name, 
type -> where type is 'History'
}
```

And i need to update attribute imageUrl from table question WHERE quiz type is for example 'History', i'm not sure how i can join this tables when using UPDATE. I tried something like this but it's not working like i want.

```
UPDATE question SET image_url = 'pathToImage' FROM quiz q WHERE q.type = 'History'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do an update + join in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql)

Comment: Already checked that, but i was not able to use answers from there :(

Comment: you need a join between questions and quiz.

Comment: Can you please show me code example how to do it, im not experienced with postgress

Comment: you need to join three tables?..

Comment: Im aware of that, but i dont know how to join them when using update statement.

Comment: `question {` :: please don't invent pseudocode.Use real DDL, so that people understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is best solution that i came up with, and it worked perfectly for my migration.

```
UPDATE question SET image_url = 'https://path_to_image.com' WHERE id IN (SELECT q.id FROM question q
            JOIN group AS g ON q.groupi_id = g.id
            JOIN quiz AS qu ON qu.id = g.quiz_id
            WHERE qu.type = 'Lifestyle')
```

So basically i update image_url to all questions with ID's in sub query, and this is easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN three tables on this way:

```
UPDATE question q 
SET    image_url = 'pathToImage'
FROM   (select g.Id 
        from group g
        JOIN   quiz z
        ON     g.quizID = z.Id
        WHERE  z.type = 'History') p
ON     q.groupId = p.Id;
```

Comment: I actually already have links to images, so i need to set that link, im not sure how and where i set image url with your example ?

Comment: With your example im getting syntax error at or near "ON" (last ON where you say  q.groupId = z.Id

Comment: I cannot see pathToImage field on none of your tables.

Comment: Path to image is actually link that i want to set, its not attrbute its actually value for image_url

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
   with cte as (
      select q.id qid
      from question q
      join "group" g on g.id = groupId
      join quiz z on z.id = quizId
      where type = 'History'
    )
    UPDATE question q
      SET image_url = 'pathToImage' 
    FROM cte.qid = q.id
```

Comment: no - I didn't check it. is there an error?.. please update question with DDL and DML to reproduce your env