# Update from join returning id from other table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

I can't figure out how to do this in Postgres.

I have two tables, `foo` and `bar`:

`foo`:id, number

`bar`:id, foo_id

There is an entry in `bar` that corresponds to and entry in `foo`. I want to update foo and return the `bar` id when I do so. I though something like this would work, but I'm having a very difficult time getting join updates to work in Postgres.

I want to do something like this:

```
UPDATE 
    foo f 
INNER JOIN
    bar b 
ON 
    f.id = b.foo_id 
SET 
    f.number = 1 
RETURNING 
    b.id
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is off, try this instead:

```
UPDATE foo AS f
SET number = 1
FROM bar AS b
WHERE f.id = b.foo_id
RETURNING b.id
```

There are many references out there which could have shown you how to phrase an update join in Postgres, [Stack Overflow being one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql).

Comment: Thanks you so much!