# SQL Updating column in new table with arithmetic function from column in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have two tables:

part of Table1:

```
 id  |  per  |  va   | gp | minutes 
-----+-------+-------+----+---------
   1 | 11.87 |  14.5 | 69 |    16.1
   2 | 17.07 | 154.9 | 78 |    23.9
   3 |  4.30 |  -8.6 | 21 |     4.4
   4 |  5.68 | -42.2 | 52 |     9.3
   5 | 19.46 | 347.8 | 82 |    32.1
   6 | 18.26 | 125.3 | 47 |    23.3
   7 | 12.76 |  79.0 | 82 |    28.5
   8 |  9.19 |  -3.7 | 13 |    14.8
   9 | 21.15 |  10.7 | 10 |     6.8
  10 | 14.38 |  46.1 | 31 |    25.7
```

Table2:

```
 player |           prl           | position 
--------+-------------------------+----------
 1      |                         | 
 2      |                         | 
 3      |                         | 
 4      |                         |
```

I'm trying to calculate prl by taking those columns in table 1 and doing per - ((67*va)/(gp*minutes)). I can of course calculate this outside of inserting it into the prl column but can't find a way to get it into prl. The closest I've gotten is by doing this:

```
update hwk2
set prl = per - ((67*va)/(gp*minutes)) from more_player_stats;
UPDATE 1904
```

which gives me the same result throughout the entire prl column. Can anyone help out this brand new sql user?

Comment: Can you tell us how these two tables are logically connected?

Comment: The first table is a bunch of NBA stats from players, but it doesn't list the players' position. So there's this stat an NBA analyst created that is the 'prl', and its formula is what I described. Basically the prl should take about 4 values (11.5 for power forwards, 11 for point guards, 10.6 for centers, etc.) So I am trying to get the players' position from the columns in Table 1 if that helps and calculate each players' 'prl' based on these stats.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question.  How do we connect players in the second table to stats in the first table?

Comment: Oh, that's already done. I inserted the players column already as just an id number - I'm just trying to get just the prl column to equal that formula in the original post.

Comment: We're going in circles.  We already know that the second table has numbered players.  But what is not clear is how to connect those players to the first table.

Comment: My apologies!! I just edited my post - the id number in Table 1 is = player # in Table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an update join:

```
UPDATE hwk2 AS t1
SET prl = t1.per - ((67*t1.va) / (t1.gp*t1.minutes))
FROM more_player_stats AS t2
WHERE t1.player = t2.id;
```

Here is a [link to a reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql) on SO covering updates in Postgres.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried this and keep getting a HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: I was missing an alias in there.  Not sure about casting; if all columns invovled are numeric there should be no issue.

Comment: Thanks so much - this is very helpful. I'll play around with it. Probably something weird in table I did. Appreciate it!

Comment: I just got it! I had to do where t1.player::numeric = t2.id::numeric; Not sure why, but I got it. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is strange, but glad you figured it out.