# How to update records based from another table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in Postgres

```
TableA
id, item_id, parent_id
1     i1        null
2     i2         1 -> match the id of the first record (1)
3     i3         2 -> match the id of the second record (2)

TableB
parent_id, item_id
  null           i1
   i1            i2         
   i2            i3
```

`i1` is the top level, `i2` is the second level and `i3` is the third level.

I need to update the `parent_id` column in `table A` to have `1` and `2` based on the `table B`.

I have

```
Update TableA set parent_id = ? (SELECT id from TableA WHERE TableA.item_id = TableB.parent_id)
from TableB
where TableB.parent_id = TableA.item_id
```

The above is basically what I need but I am not sure the exact systax to do it. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try this answer.  You can do what your asking using an UPDATE FROM statement with a JOIN.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to update parent_id based on TableB record. I need to find the record in TableB and use it to update parent_id in TableA. 

Notice parent_id in TableA is null, 1 , 2 not i1, i2.

Comment: You just need to tweak the values in the answer linked.  The syntax is available there.  I also see a new answer to the question that seems appropriate.

Comment: Why is `parent_id` a string in one table and an integer in the other?  The naming makes it hard for me to understand the question.  You appear to want the "depth" in the first table, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What **I think** (your not very clear) you want is something like this(not tested):

```
Update TableA set parent_id = TableA_parent.id
from TableB
inner join TableA TableA_parent
  on TableB.parent_id = TableA_parent.item_id
where TableB.item_id = TableA.item_id
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.