# PostgreSQL query to map one table's id to another table with many to one criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to map a `contributor_id` in my `archive` table to a `contributor_id` in my `sales` table.  The `archive` table has 120k entries and the `sales` table has 20k. The `sales` table has an 'uploaded_filename' field, as does the `archive` table.

The `sales` table's `uploaded_filename`s are often repeated multiple times in the `archive` table.

My question is how do I write a query that maps the `contributor_id` in the `archive` to the corresponding `uploaded_filename`

Table Design (I'm omitting extraneous fields)

Archive:

| uploaded_filename | contributor_id |

Sales (at present):

| uploaded_filename |

My attempt:

```
UPDATE sales
SET contributor_id = a.contributor_id
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN archive a 
ON a.uploaded_filename = s.uploaded_filename;
```

Comment: In Postgres's SQL , you should **not** repeat the target table in the `from` list. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql/7869611#7869611

Comment: If you remove the "FROM sales" line I think that's basically the query you want.

Comment: Why are you repeating data like *uploaded_filename* across related tables? One of the cornerstones of the relational database model is to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Thanks for the help (this is all inherited data) --- I was able to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql and solve it

Comment: Also,your logic is flawed. There could be multiple *different* contributer_ids for the same updated_filename and you can choose only one for the update.