# Sql procedure to update a column of a table for multiple conditions as given in sample

Tags: postgresql

there are two tables with following columns and dataset:

```
      emp_details                  emp_value
emp_id--user_id--emp_name    emp_id--user_id--emp_name_val
123      111      CR          123     111        1
124      111      Gr          124     111        2
```

I want to update the value of emp_name_val=3 for emp_id=124 when
emp_id=123 and emp_name_val=1.Need a procedure to update the values when there 
are such multiple conditions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do an update + join in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql)

Comment: It's not answered in the given question.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE emp_value
SET emp_name_val = 3
FROM emp_value inner join emp_details using(emp_id)
WHERE emp_id=123 and emp_name_val =1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code so others can learn from what you've done. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22419774).