# How to update the column when the condition is true using CASE

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a table `LOADING_ZONE` with columns

---

```
aid, a_name, addrid, addr1, addr2, city, pstate, country, postalcd, contactnumber, attendancekey, 
attendancedate, attendedyesno
```

---

and another table `STAGE_TABLE` with columns

---

```
aid, a_name, addrid, addr1, addr2, city, pstate, country, postalcd, contactnumber, attendancekey, 
attendancedate, attendedyesno,action_indicator
```

---

I have inserted the data from loading_zone into stage_table using:

```
INSERT INTO stage_table(aid, a_name, addrid, addr1, addr2, city, pstate, country, postalcd, 
contactnumber, attendancekey, attendancedate, attendedyesno)
 

SELECT aid, a_name, addrid, addr1, addr2, city, pstate, country, postalcd, contactnumber, attendancekey, attendancedate, attendedyesno
```

```
FROM loading_zone
```

and I want to make action_indicator as 'U' when there exists same aid in both tables else 'I'

I tried this but receiving an error:

> assign= "update stage_table set action_indicator = (CASE when loading_zone.aid=stage_table.aid  then 'U' else 'I' end)"

The error is:

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: missing FROM-clause entry for table "loading_zone"
>
> LINE 1: ...ate stage_table set action_indicator = (CASE when loading_zone...

Comment: Check out the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql

Comment: When you `INSERT` into `stage_table`, there's no existing row, and therefore no existing aid to compare with. Therefore, since you are `INSERT`ing the `aid` from `loading_zone`, after the `INSERT` is done, `aid` will be the same for both tables, so you might as well hard-code `action_indicator='U'` -- if this understanding is incorrect, please clarify your question.  Further, if you are looking to `UPDATE`, can you indicate their relationship (i.e., which col is primary key, and are there foreign keys involved?)

Comment: yes,  that is what I want to make but then if I create aid as primary key I am receiving duplicates error so in order to avoid it I made an extra column **stg** as primary key with datatype as serial

Comment: update stage_table set action_indicator = CASE  
                        WHEN loading_zone.aid=stage_table.aid THEN 'U' 
                        ELSE 'I'
                    END  
from loading_zone try this.

Comment: yeah, Thank you It worked after a long time @BhartiMohane

Answer (score 0):

I have created two sample tables(test and test1) against STAGE_TABLE and LOADING_ZONE  to replicate the use case at my end. Following update query will give you the expected output.

```
create table test (aid integer, action_indicator character varying(1));
create table test1 (aid integer);

insert into test(aid) values(1);
insert into test(aid) values(2);
insert into test(aid) values(3);
insert into test(aid) values(4);

insert into test1(aid) values(1);
insert into test1(aid) values(2);
insert into test1(aid) values(3);


update test set action_indicator=a.action_indicator from (select aid,case when test.aid in(select aid from test1) then 'U' else 'I' end as action_indicator 
from test)a where a.aid=test.aid

select * from test
```

Output

```
1   "U"
2   "U"
3   "U"
4   "I"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update`:

```
update stage_table st
    set action_indicator =
        (case when exists (select 1
                           from loading_zone lz
                           where lz.aid = st.aid
                          )
              then 'U' else 'I'
         end);
```

If you initialize all the indicators to `'I'` (using either `UPDATE` or `DEFAULT`), then you can do this when you insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO stage_table (aid, a_name
                         addrid, addr1, addr2, city, pstate, country, postalcd,
                         contactnumber, attendancekey, attendancedate, attendedyesno,
                         action_indicator
                        )
    SELECT aid, a_name,
           addrid, addr1, addr2, city, pstate, country, postalcd,
           contactnumber, attendancekey, attendancedate, attendedyesno,
           'U'
    FROM loading_zone;
```