# how to not update all rows and only restrict to the where clause

Tags: postgresql

I have an update query in postgres as such:

```
update table1 e
set (col1,col2) = 
(select col1,col2 from table2 se
where  e.id = se.id and se.col2 is not null);
```

However this updates all rows even the ones that are nulls for  `se.col2`. The rows are updated as nulls. I want to just update where `se.col2 is not null` . Not all rows.

Comment: use where query after subquery

Comment: tried, but .... ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "se"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple if you use the (non-standard) `FROM` clause of `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table1 e
SET (col1, col2) = (se.col1, se.col2)
FROM table2 se
WHERE e.id = se.id AND se.col2 IS NOT NULL;
```

This assumes that `table2.id` is unique, or at least that no more than one row of `table2` matches any given `table1` row.

Comment: yeah i understand , otherwise this will fail silently ... it will update unwanted rows...

Comment: Are you [sure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75592208/4808122) to get an *error*, test in version 14 shows undeterministic update with the *first* value...

Comment: Well this would mean that the behaviour is even more *undeterministic* than I thought. But I would argue that it is in the responsibility of the query designer to join on a unique key in this case.

Comment: yes i was surprised that it gives an error since the documentation on update gives an example which specifically talks about giving unwanted results https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Hm, I must have misremembered.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
update table1 e
set (col1,col2) = (
  select col1,col2 from table2 se
  where  e.id = se.id
)
where exists (
  select id from table2 se2 
  where se2.id = e.id 
  and col2 is not null
);
```

[DB Fiddle to play with.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uNBKrhdYAXfkaV9hahRAjg/0)