update duplicate rows based on latest date in postgres database
My requirement is to keep the latest vin and reject the duplicate vin by updating the error_status as 'y'.
query:
UPDATE vin_table u INNER JOIN (SELECT vin, MAX(date) AS max_date FROM 
vin_table where m_job_id='1c1b9440' GROUP BY vin) t ON u.vin = t.vin 
SET u.error_status = 'y' WHERE u.date <> t.max_date and 
m_job_id='1c1b9440';

error: syntax error at or near "INNER JOIN"

expected result:


You have a syntax problem: look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869592/how-to-do-an-update-join-in-postgresql  the set statement occurs before the join.  Also how do you want to handle duplicates for Vin/Date should they exist or is Vin/Date a key/unique index?

Is this a problem with MySQL or with PostgreSQL? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Syntax depends on the database you are using, see examples here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293347/8093576

@NicoHaase above i have mentioned the requirement. can you please check provide the PostgreSQL for that.

DbFiddle Demo  Assuming Postgres
UPDATE Vin_table 
set error_status = 'y'
WHERE (vin,Date) not in (
  SELECT vin, min(date) 
  FROM vin_table 
  GROUP BY vin);

WARNING:
If a VIN has multiple occurrences on the same date and that date is the "most recent", then you will have multiple "Newest" records.   As you've not explained what needs to happen with duplicates should they occur, nor indicated if Vin/Date is a unique index/primary key, I've assumed leaving them both as Error_status 'n' is acceptable.
To support a VIN having multiple records with the same date, we either need a time, or some other attribute to guarantee the "most current" record or knowledge that Vin/Date is unique; such as a unique index or combined key on those 2 fields.
I also assume VIN and Date will always have a value and neither field will be null.
I further assume all error_status are set to 'n' to begin with and I don't need to adjust any y's to n's based on a "newer" newest record. Otherwise we need to evaluate each record or run two updates.
I encourage you to play around with null values in VIN/date field or duplicates using the demo provided so you can better understand some assumptions we have to make and the impacts on your expected results.
RESULTS:
+-------+----------+--------------+----------+
|  vin  |   date   | error_status | m_job_id |
+-------+----------+--------------+----------+
| A1C2  | 20240520 | n            | 1c1b9440 |
| A1C2  | 20240521 | y            | 1c1b9440 |
| A1C2  | 20240522 | y            | 1c1b9440 |
| A1C21 | 20240520 | n            | 1c1b9440 |
| A1C23 | 20240520 | n            | 1c1b9440 |
| A1C23 | 20240521 | y            | 1c1b9440 |
+-------+----------+--------------+----------+

